# C: Any way to convert text string to float, i.e. 1e100?

Tags: c, string, math

Unfortunately in this log I have there are some strings with that notation (1.00e4), I know I can use printf with the `"%e"` specifier to create that notation, how would I read it?

Unfortunately strtof and scanf seem to return 0.00000 on "1e100", would I need to write my own parser for this?

*(updated)*

What I have as input:
string "4.1234567e5", or "4.5e5"

Desired output:
float 412345.67, or integer "450000"

Comment: What exactly is your input and what is your desired output?

Comment: I had updated with an example, PHP seems to be able to parse strings in to numbers easily, it must be somewhat simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    double val;
    double val2 = 1e100;
    sscanf ("1e100", "%lf", &val);  // that's an letter ELL, not a number WUN !
    printf ("%lf\n", val);          // so is that.
    printf ("%lf\n", val2);         // and that.
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
10000000000000000159028911097599180468360810000000000...
10000000000000000159028911097599180468360810000000000...
```

The reason it's not exactly 1<sup>100</sup> is because of the nature of IEEE754 floating point values. Changing it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double val;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        sscanf (argv[i], "%lf", &val);
        printf ("   '%s' -> %e\n", argv[i], val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and running it with your sample arguments gives:

```
pax$ ./qq 4.1234567e5 4.5e5 3.47e10 3.47e-10
   '4.1234567e5' -> 4.123457e+05
   '4.5e5' -> 4.500000e+05
   '3.47e10' -> 3.470000e+10
   '3.47e-10' -> 3.470000e-10
```

Comment: Darn, this is what I came up with, but I just tested and `1e-5` for example fails, so that negative notation with scanf not possible?

Comment: Suggest you try again, @Tim, that works fine for me, two lines with `0.000010`. Put my second code block in exactly as it is.

Comment: That is strange, it works for that, but something like `sscanf ("3.47e-10", "%lf", &val);` does not and returns 0.00000 (atleast on my GCC compiler, I am not sure if something is wrong or it is a limitation)

Comment: I get `34700000000.000000` for that. Are you sure you're using a **double** rather than a float?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm actually _using_ gcc. Version 4.3.4 under CygWin 1.7.

Comment: sizeof on my double returns 8 as expected, I can't be using that unique a configuration, just GCC 4.4.5 on Ubuntu - I hate strange things like this, I guess i'll try on another machine tomorrow.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, my mistake, I used positive exponent. The reason you're getting 0.0000 is because the default for `printf (%lf)` is to show 6 decimals only and all your digits are past that point. So the scanf is working but the printf needs modifying if you want to see it.

Comment: Excellent, I was coming to the same conclusion of printf being at fault. I had learned 5-6 things doing this, many thanks :)

Comment: @Tim: If you can learn 5 or 6 new things in twenty minutes, you can probably take the rest of the week off :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use also

```
double atof( const char * str );
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work if I use float data type. Perhaps the problem lies there.

Comment: Well, 1e100 is not representable as a float, they only go up to 1e38 or something like that. Doubles will go up to 1e307-ish.